# php echo rich text from code in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, richtext

I am wondering how to echo data stored in a database as rich text.   I can put the data in the database, but it stores it as code.   I want it to echo as formatted text using PHP.  For example, if one of my users inputs the chemical formula CO<sub>2</sub> with the 2 subscripted, it will be stored in the MySQL database as the code:

```
     CO<sub>2</sub>
```

I don't want this code to be echoed.  Instead I want the formatted text "CO<sub>2</sub>" to be echoed.   Is this possible and if so how?   I would like all the rich text markup to be echoed instead as actual formatted text rather than code.

Comment: Simply asking PHP to `echo` the contents of the database should achieve exactly what you want.  It sounds like you're running the value retrieved from the database through an escaping function, like `htmlentities()`?  However, you absolutely must ensure that any data you output without escaping is *clean*—if you store arbitrary user-provided data in that table, you could be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: This is how I'm echoing:  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      
      echo $row['Question'].'|'.$row['AnswerA'].'|'.$row['AnswerB'].'|'."bl3nq".$row['AnswerC'].'|'."bl3nq".$row['AnswerD'].'|'."bl3nq".$row['AnswerE'].'|'.$row['rightanswer'].'|'.$row['scrambleanswers'].'|'."noimg".$row['image'].'|'."bl3nq".$row['feedback'].'|'."bl3nq".$row['imagesource'].'|';

}
I don't think I'm using any unusual escape function.  Does PDO do this automatically, perhaps?

Comment: No, PDO doesn't escape automatically.  Are you sure the data is stored in the database unescaped?  Perhaps you escaped it prior to insertion?

Comment: If I am storing in the MySQL database as VARCHAR, would this cause the problem?   Do I need to change to TEXT perhaps?

Comment: No, that would not make any difference.

Comment: I am not sure if it is escaping prior to insertion.  How would I be able to tell?   It is inserted in the database as code.  For example: CO<sub>2</sub>

Comment: Are you *sure*?  How have you verified that?

Comment: I looked in phpmyadmin and this is what is visible there.

Comment: I don't know whether phpMyAdmin escapes data before returning it; if it doesn't, then you'd see `CO<sub>2</sub>` even though the database contains `CO&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;` (which it probably does, given that CKEditor escapes HTML by default—see [my other comment, below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34683173/php-echo-rich-text-from-code-in-a-mysql-database?noredirect=1#comment57114342_34683355)).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the PHP script is echoing the text correctly, but that my user front-end (an HTML5/javascript application) is then taking the echoed formatted text and writing it as code.   So, in short, the echoing is working in php.  Now I just need to figure out how to cause my front-end application to show the text as rich text, not code.

Answer (score -1):

Before insert in your database use htmlspecialchars($string);

Example:

```
$string = "CO<sub>2</sub>";
$stringToInsert = htmlspecialchars($string);
```

After insert the $stringToInsert in your database, you can print into your page like this:

```
$decodedString = htmlspecialchars_decode($stringToInsert);
echo $decodedString;
```

I preffer using htmlspecialchars instead of htmlentities for this case.

Comment: Hi Pablo, This is being inserted with a plugin: ckeditor  so I don't know how to change the way it is entered, but it is entered as code.   The problem I am having is that I want it to echo as formatted text, not code.

Comment: @brett: [CKEditor escapes HTML by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700383/ckeditor-is-escaping-html-elements).

Comment: it looks like the echoing is fine when I check the echo, but my html5/javascript application front end is re-writing it as code again.   Not sure how to fix this yet.   If you have any ideas, that would be great.

Comment: Can you showme what is the data stored in your database?
is:   CO<sub>2</sub> or something like "CO&lt;sub&gt;2&lt;/sub&gt;" ?

Comment: If you have the seccond one you can just use: html_entity_decode()

Comment: It is storing the first way: CO<sub>2</sub>

Comment: Oh, then you should just echo without any special function. But, where are you trying to echo this string?
I mean, inside of a rich text editor or something like that?