# How to prevent JavaScript injection, but provide a ckeditor with code formatter

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, ckeditor

I have created a website based on

```
SQL Server 2014
C# (ASP.NET)
Javascript and jQuery
```

The user can store information within a textbox on my site.
To prevent injection, I can use encode / decode from special character.
The user should be able to submit code like below but the code should not executed. So far so good.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('uuuuups.....');
    });
</script>
```

This code will be stored as is to database. (without encoding first).
Now I would like to offer a ckeditor to my users and give the ability to use the code-plugin. The code-plugin itself creates the following code:

```
<pre class="brush:jscript;">
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log(&#39;uuuuups....&#39;);
    });
&lt;/script&gt;</pre>
```

I have tried to replace charcter within SQL like

```
replace(replace(@text, '<', '&lt;'), '>', '&gt;')
```

But this seems to break the code when I try to view.
My problem now is, how to handle this?
Do I have encode twice?
Every hint will be appreciated.

Comment: You may think about somthing like Sanitize HTML: https://github.com/gbirke/Sanitize.js for example

Comment: [CKEditor is escaping html elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700383/ckeditor-is-escaping-html-elements)

Answer (score 0):

i am using ckeditor in my web site, and i face the same issue, it is about ***javascript injection***. how to prevent it without disrupting the view.
Try in your server side to parse the `"< script ...>javascript code ...</script>"` and clear it. I think it is not difficult to find this tag in asp.net nor in php.

Good luck

Comment: Kindly provide code snippet/detailed answer for it to help!